# How can I remove music that I do not want from noise?

Tags: music

I know how to import to the noise library, but is there way to remove music that I have already imported, without removing everything?

Answer (score 4):

Yes it is possible.

1. Right Click on the track you want to delete and select the last option asking to "Delete from library". Refer the first picture.
2. A new Popup appears. The first option is to *delete the music from the library and the pc*, the second one is *cancel option* and the last one is your choice. It(last option) deletes the track only from the library. Refer the second picture.

**Delete Track from Library - first picture**
[image]

**Popup - second picture**
[image]